# Get callers namespace in clojure

Tags: logging, clojure, namespaces

I wrapped a logging library in Clojure; Let's call the namespace of this `foo.logger`. Now I have another namespace like `bar.baz` and from there I call the logger.

Is there some idiomatic/nice way, that I can determine the namespace of the callers namespace inside the logger? I don't want to set this as parameter for the logger ;-)

Comment: Why the Java tag if you're asking about Clojure? Please be sure to tag your questions accurately.

Comment: Because Clojure is compiled to ByteCode and if someone has a good answer in Java, I can adapt this!

Comment: By that logic, why not tag it with Scala too? That's compiled to bytecode too.

Comment: Clojure people consider it idiomatic to use Java solutions, but not Scala, Kotlin, JRuby, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one of those rare cases where using a macro is a solid choice.

Making that a macro that prints the value of `*ns` will get the value of `*ns*` in the callers space because the macro will expand and run in that namespace.

```
(defmacro log [msg]
  `(printf "%s:%s\n" ~*ns* ~msg))
```

Try to be aware of "macro contagion" around this because anything that wants to extend this function will need to also be a macro, though I have been doing this for the last six years and it hasn't been a problem often.

Comment: Beautiful and good to know, that macros will expand in the callers namespace :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% correct solution but works for most cases:

```
(some->> (.getStackTrace (Thread/currentThread))               
         (map #(re-matches #"^([^$]+)\$.+" (.getClassName %))) 
         (keep last)
         (dedupe)
         (second)
         (symbol)
         (find-ns))
```